# weird time series plots when adding the dates on the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plotly

I'm trying to plot a time series on python using plotly, here is the result without the dates on the x-axis :

[image]

And when I add the date :

[image]

Here is a view of my table :

```
{'sasdate': {4: Timestamp('1959-01-09 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('1959-01-12 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('1960-01-03 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('1960-01-06 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('1960-01-09 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('1960-01-12 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('1961-01-03 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('1961-01-06 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('1961-01-09 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('1961-01-12 00:00:00')},
 'CDT': {4: 0.9633000000000003,
  5: 0.35329999999999995,
  6: 0.6134,
  7: 1.2666999999999997,
  8: 1.4733,
  9: 1.5799999999999996,
  10: 1.4367,
  11: 1.4867,
  12: 1.6766999999999999,
  13: 1.5133},
 'crise': {4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0},
 'prev': {4: 0.187232436694447,
  5: 0.3105689948109355,
  6: 0.2539228791308063,
  7: 0.13916924600664243,
  8: 0.11171277377207611,
  9: 0.09915690331613247,
  10: 0.11627115062260285,
  11: 0.1100762567460945,
  12: 0.08869839928964451,
  13: 0.10687875779138178}}
```

And here is the code of the plot :

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(test,x='sasdate', y="prev", labels = 'ligne')


fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.01
))

fig.update_layout(showlegend =True)

fig.show()
```

It seems the plots doesn't consider all the observations of the series. My 'date' features is on a datetime format, the problem is the same with matplotlib.

Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframe as well as the code you used to produce your line chart? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` into your question, and that would help us debug the behavior you're seeing – thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You dates are in the wrong format. They need to be YYYY-MM-DD rather than YYYY-DD-MM, e.g., swap '1959-01-09 00:00:00' to be '1959-09-01 00:00:00' as so on, and the plot will look as expected.

If you don't want to do the conversion manually, you could use the `datetime` package and tell it the format of the date/time that you have, by doing something like:

```py
from datetime import datetime

test["sasdate"] = {
    i: Timestamp(datetime.strptime(str(test["sasdate"][i]), "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))
    for i in test["sasdate"]
}
```

If `test` is already a DataFrame, then you could do:

```py
from pandas import Series

test["sasdate"] = Series(
    [
        Timestamp(datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")) for date in test["sasdate"]
    ],
    index=test["sasdate"].index
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it doesn't seem to work. When I run your code to change the date format, I got this error :

KeyError: Timestamp('1959-01-09 00:00:00')

Comment: I think I'm missing a closing bracket. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've fixed the brackets and moved the `str` to the correct place.

Comment: I still have the same error. I have the impression the code hasn't changed, I run : 
test["sasdate"] = {
    i: Timestamp(datetime.strptime(str(test["sasdate"][i]), "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))
    for i in test["sasdate"]
}

and I have : Timestamp('1959-01-09 00:00:00')

Comment: When I copy the clip of data you have provided into a dictionary called `test`, it works for me. What type of object is `test` for you? Is is actually a pandas Dataframe?

Comment: Yes it's a data frame, in reality, it's a slice of a bigger data frame.

Comment: I've added to the answer with what to do if it's a DataFrame already.

Answer (score 0):

As @MattPitkin said, it was a problem with my date time format. I changed it with these transformations :

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
df["date"]  = df["date"].apply(lambda x : x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: it's helpful to see how to fix the format, but ultimately Matt Pitkin has the solution... it's good practice to mark responses that are helpful and/or have the solution.